# Basic matrix algebra. How is this step derived?

Tags: matrices, quaternions

I am fairly new to matrix algebra and I do not know how to derive this step. I am reading this report of Quaternion Kinematics: 
http://www.iri.upc.edu/people/jsola/JoanSola/objectes/notes/kinematics.pdf

In the page 16, it takes the expression:

$\dot{\mathbf{R}^\intercal}\mathbf{R}+\mathbf{R}^\intercal \dot{\mathbf{R}}=0$,

and reduces it to:

$\mathbf{R}^\intercal\dot{\mathbf{R}}=-(\mathbf{R}^\intercal\dot{\mathbf{R}})^\intercal$,

These are rotation matrices. What steps are in between?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Given matrices $A$ and $B$, $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$, provided the dimensions of the matrices are such that the multiplication of the matrices can be done.

Comment: From $\dot{R}^TR+R^T\dot{R}=0$, subtract $\dot{R}^TR$ from both sides.  Next, recognize that $(R^T\dot{R})^T=\dot{R}^TR$ using the property that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ and that $(A^T)^T=A$

Answer (score 0):

Observe $$\dot{R}^TR+R^T\dot{R}=0\Rightarrow R^T\dot{R}=-\dot{R}^TR$$ and use $A=(A^T)^T$ and then $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ to obtain $$\dot{R}^TR=\left(\left(\dot{R}^TR\right)^T\right)^T=\left(R^T\left(\dot{R}^T\right)^T\right)^T=\left(R^T\dot{R}\right)^T.$$